# Javascript retorna undefined al volver a ejecutar la funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, function, undefined

Buen día a todos, tengo una función "ServerTypeChange" que cuando la ejecuto por primera vez desde el document ready si realiza lo indicado. Lo que debe realizar es ocultar todos los elementos que tengan la clase indicada, dejando únicamente los que no la tienen.

Y tengo un select que cuando su valor cambia, el valor de una variable también lo hace y después manda a llamar a la función mencionada, Si realiza el cambio de la variable indicada, pero la función antes mencionada, ya no hace nada y solo retorna "undefined"

Este es el código:

```
<script>
var TypeServerSelected = 0;
var remotes = document.getElementsByClassName("db_remote");
var dss = document.getElementsByClassName("db_ds");
var locales = document.getElementsByClassName("db_local");

$(document).ready(function(){
  ServerTypeChange();


});

$('#TypeServer').change(function (){
  TypeServerSelected = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  ServerTypeChange();
});

function ServerTypeChange(){
  switch(TypeServerSelected){
    case 0: //local
          console.log("Ejecutando 0");
          for (var i = 0; i < remotes.length; i++){
              remotes[i].style.display = "none";
          }


          for (var i = 0; i < dss.length; i++){
              dss[i].style.display = "none";
          }


          for (var i = 0; i < locales.length; i++){
              locales[i].style.display = "block";
          }


    break;
    case 1: //remote
    console.log("Ejecutando 1");
          for (var i = 0; i < dss.length; i++){
              dss[i].style.display = "none";
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < locales.length; i++){
              locales[i].style.display = "none";
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < remotes.length; i++){
              remotes[i].style.display = "block";
          }
    break;
    case 2: //hospedado
    console.log("Ejecutando 2");
          for (var i = 0; i < locales.length; i++){
              locales[i].style.display = "none";
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < remotes.length; i++){
              remotes[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < dss.length; i++){
              dss[i].style.display = "block";
          }
    break;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Revisa con un console.log que `TypeServerSelected ` reciba un valor antes de llamar de nuevo a la función, en el evento `change` de jquery.

Comment: Si lo hace, me muestra el nuevo valor y es correcto.

Comment: No veo ningún valor de retorno dentro de la función, a que te refieres con que te devuelve `undefined`, haces alguna otra operación?

Comment: No, solamente ejecuto el mostrar y ocultar elementos, no retorno algo manualmente

Pero al hacer el cambio de selección en el select, está función simplemente no hace nada, ni siquiera accede a ella.

He colocado un console.log("entro"), justo al inicio de mi función "ServerTypeChange" pero ni eso lo muestra, inmediatamente dice "undefined"

Comment: Puedes poner tu html?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al asignar el valor del select a la variable se asignaba como texto, no como numero.

Entonces ya no entraba en ninguno de mis casos

Comment: Excelente. Que bueno que lo resolviste.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.